# How to validate existing bill number in new bill generation and not in update case of same generated bill?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, logic

I am writing a stored procedure for bill number existence. I pass just bill number as parameter. I want that when we create a new bill and user inputs number of an already generated bill it returns the bill details in this query. While if that bill is opened in update mode then it returns nothing as its the same bill. I have tried a lot and the update mode is working but new bill case is also giving the same response. Kindly help.
Below is my SP

```
DECLARE @billID AS INT;
            SELECT  @billID = billID
            FROM    dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billInfo
            WHERE   billNumber = 'GW-090'
            PRINT @billID
            IF @billID = NULL
                BEGIN
                    PRINT 'new'
                    SELECT  billNumber
                    FROM    dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billInfo
                    WHERE   billNumber = 'GW-090'
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    PRINT 'update'
                    IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  billNumber
                                    FROM    dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billInfo
                                    WHERE   billNumber = 'GW-090'
                                            AND billID != 154 )
                        BEGIN
                            SELECT  billNumber
                            FROM    dbo.eInvoice_tbl_billInfo
                            WHERE   billNumber = 'GW-090'
                                            AND billID != 154
                        END

                END
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: did you verified the value IF billID = NULL is being satisfied over here  in your new case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By just adding a new parameter of bill ID from server-side this problem is resolved.

Comment: Regardless, as per your code, `IF @billID = NULL` will never be true which means it will never execute the statements meant for 'New' Bill Ids.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your null comparison to:

```
 IF @billID is NULL
```

instead of

```
 IF @billID = NULL
```

It comes down to how SQL treats null with comparison operators. Try running the following to, hopefully, make more sense of it:

```
DECLARE @billID AS INT;
set @billID = NULL
PRINT iif(@billID is null, 'same', 'different')
PRINT iif(@billID = null, 'same', 'different')
PRINT iif(null is null, 'same', 'different')
PRINT iif(null = null, 'same', 'different')
```